# Flexbox 4 элемента, 2 по середине, 2 по краям во всю высоту

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка, flexbox

Собственно нужно такое строение:[image: пример]

Прошу помощи, ломаю голову, не могу понять как такое сделать с flex-box'ами, а время ограничено. Знаю, что можно сделать 3 элемента и в среднем еще 2, но хотелось бы почище, без доп-ых элементов. С flex элементами знаком не долго.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По идее так:

```
.container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}
.container-2-3{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
```

Для общего контейнера задается стиль отображения флекс в ряд, а для среднего контейнера, содержащего второй и третий блоки - стиль отображения флекс в колонку.
Без дополнительной обертки для второго и третьего блоков, по-моему, не получится :(

Comment: Походу и правда не получиться, раз мы вдвоем не смогли придумать. Получается не такой уж он и гибкий, этот flexbox.